# backbone Uncaught ReferenceError on second render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im building a backbone app and stumbled upon a trouble.
On first load the template loads fine, but on router navigation i get the reference error.

Here's the code:

template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="testTpl">
        <div class="cabinet">
            Its a test! <%= userName %>.
            <a href="#/">Go back</a>
        </div>        
    </script>

<script type="text/template" id="secondTpl">
        <div class="cabinet">
            Its a second test! <%= test %>.
            <a href="#/">Go back</a>
        </div>        
    </script>
```

Router:

```
var Controller = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: { 
        "!/test": "test", 
        "!/second": "second"
    },
    test: function () {
        if (Views.Test!= null) {
            Views.Test.render();
        }
    },
    second: function () {
        if (Views.Second!= null) {
            Views.Second.render();
        }
    }
});
```

Views:

```
var Block = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function (options) {
    var userName = {userName:'success!', test: 1};
    var tpl = _.template(this.options.template);
        $(this.el).html(tpl(userName));
    }
});

Views = { 
            Test: new Block({el:$('#block'), template: $('#testTpl').html()}),
            Second: new Block({el:$('#block'), template: $('#secondTpl').html()})
        };
```

**On first load**, everything works fine, template loads the variables, but after that, following # links results in

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: userName is not defined
```

What could possibly go wrong here? Why does directly making an object

```
userName = {userName:'success!', test: 1}
```

and using it in template break the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in 1.1, Backbone Views no longer have the options argument attached as this.options automatically.

So your code is not compatible with latest Backbone. To fix it just add some code to "initialize" function of your view:

```
initialize: function ( options ) {
    this.template = options.template;
}
```

After this i tested your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/RS88E/1/
And everything seems to be OK.